# can I use any other page instead of HTML like JSP ... etc in apache wicket framework?

Tags: apache, jsp, wicket

I am having web application in wicket application and I want to include jsp page in that so can I use any other page instead of HTML like JSP ... etc in apache wicket framework if yes then how to configure wicket framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your Wicket application with `getRequestCycleSettings().setBufferResponse(false)`.

otherwise your Wicket page will be flushed out after the JSP that’s included immediately.

Refer [Jsp and Wicket Sitting on same Tree](http://herebebeasties.com/2007-03-01/jsp-and-wicket-sitting-in-a-tree/)   :)